# NGINX (Operation not permitted) while reading upstream

Tags: nginx

I have NGINX working as a cache engine and can confirm that pages are being cached as well as being served from the cache. But the error logs are getting filled with this error:

> 2018/01/19 15:47:19 [crit] 107040#107040: *26 chmod()
>   "/etc/nginx/cache/nginx3/c0/1d/61/ddd044c02503927401358a6d72611dc0.0000000007"
>   failed (1: Operation not permitted) while reading upstream, client:
>   xx.xx.xx.xx, server: *.---.com, request: "GET /support/applications/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/support/applications/",
>   host: "---.com"

I'm not really sure what the source of this error could be since NGINX is working. Are these errors that can be safely ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not explained in the original question is that the mounted storage is an Azure file share. So in the FSTAB I had to include the gid= and uid= for the desired owner. This then removed the need for chown and chmod also became unnecessary. This removed the chmod() error but introduced another.

Then I was getting errors on rename() without permission to perform  this. At this point I scrapped what I was doing, moved to a different type of Azure storage (specifically a Disk attached to the VM) and all these problems went away.

So I'm offering this as an answer but realistically, the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 1):

We noticed the same problem. Following the guide from Microsoft @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv#create-a-storage-class seems to have fixed it.

In our case the nginx process was using a different user for the worker threads, so we needed to find that user's uid and gid and use that in the StorageClass definition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using nginx proxy caching, but nginx does not have the ability to manipulate files in it's cache directory. You will need to get the ownership/permissions correct on the cache directory.

Comment: I agree but if that was true, how can nginx create the directories and insert files? I checked owner and it shows as root and if I use chown to set as the www-data user that nginx is running as, nothing seems to change.